# QGIS 3.4 heatmap: how to reproject layer from degrees to meters?

Tags: maps, heatmap, qgis, reprojection-error

I'm trying to follow [this youtube tutorial](https://youtu.be/o9Gqrr5cYrY?t=93) on making a heatmap in QGIS. However, my data is in degrees and not meters. The documentation for the data I'm using says the CRS should be EPSG:4326 - WGS 84, which is what I imported it as. Do I still need to reproject?

[image: An image of what I see], but I'm trying to get meters and not degrees. The data I'm using comes from [this tutorial](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/creating_heatmaps.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you set CRS to EPSG: 6487 - NAD83 (2011) / Maryland, you can enter value in terms of meters.